# onesignal push notification restrictions

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

I searched and found nothing for my question. Is there any special restriction or limitation using Onesignal web push notification? I mean different technologies for front-end and back-end or any special consideration. Or that only depends on browser?

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a new tag for your notification timeout every time user logs in and when sending notifications check this tag with your server current time.